# Recommendations for good html & css editors? (Web Application)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, editor

Is there any good html & css editors in a web application? And I don't mean those like dreamweaver and eclipse. I mean like those editors stackoverflow uses when asking a question. I tried find for html editor online, but most of the editors don't support css. Does anyone know any good ones? Preferably to be used for Ruby-on-Rails! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I truly love [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).  It's the editor that ships with WordPress, but it can be installed by itself.  It is highly configurable, supports css, and is quite powerful.

There are two versions, a javascript version and a jquery version, so it can be installed with any server technology, but there is also a [TinyMCE gem for rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails).

Comment: yup! Trying TinyMCE now. Looks amazing! But how do I add css style (codes) to the editor? Everytime when I entered the css codes and click "Update", those codes are removed. :(

Comment: This link should help you: [TinyMCE: content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css)  In particular the part halfway down the page, where it says: **Any CSS classes defined in your CSS file will show up in the styles dropdown lists (unless you explicitly set what shows up in the styles dropdown list with the theme_advanced_styles option), be they in the main editor window or in a plugin's dialogue window (for example, the advimage plugin dialogue window) because TinyMCE will generate them dynamically based on your CSS file.**

Answer (score 2):

I only use it in one place, but [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) has been pretty good. It integrates well with RailsAdmin, which is what I use it for. Look for the [ckeditor gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/).

Comment: If you want to use it commercially, you have to pay for a license.

Comment: Not strictly true. There are open source and closed source licences. If GPL, LGPL, or Mozilla's license terms work for you then you can use it commercially. http://ckeditor.com/license

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails